# Alert show and disappear after period of time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My code is working but I want to show the alert for period of time **(alert alert-warning)** and for **(alert alert-success)** I also want to show the alert for period of time but after that it reload the page.

Screen below example for the **(alert alert-warning)**
[image]

It's working but it would be great if the **alert-warning** show and disappear after a period of time (I think 3 second should be nice).

Screen below for the **(alert alert-success)**
[image]

It's also working and I also want to show and disappear after a period of time but for this alert I want after the alert disappear it's directly reload the page (without close the **x** button)

this is my index.php

[image]

this is my register.php

[image]

and this is my main.js

[image]

My problem is in main.js, I tried some code it worked, but after the alert disappear (3second), when the user tries to display it again it don't worked anymore. 
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Post code as text

Comment: You can use sweetalert plugin http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/ for this.

Comment: @Chonchol Mahmud , thanks, the plugin is nice. but i still want to know to solve the question I ask. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It didn't show because after success callback, you hide the element after 3 seconds of `setTimeout`. What you need to do is, before run `setTimeout` function, just show the element back to page like instance :

```
success : function () {
  $( '#register_message' ).show(); //show the element back
  $( '#register_message' ).html(''); // remove existing element
  $( '#register_message' ).html( data ); // adding new element coming from server side
  ...........
  the rest of the code
  ..........

}
```

**For reload :**

If the data coming from server side is an HTML code, then do like this :

```
success : function ( data ) {

   $( '#register_message' ).show(); //show the element back
   $( '#register_message' ).html(''); // remove existing element
   $( '#register_message' ).html( data ); // adding new element coming from server side

   setTimeout( function () {
      $( '#register_message' ).hide();
      // and at here you can check whether the html coming is success or error
      if ( $( data ).hasClass( 'alert-success' ) )
          location.reload();

   }, 3000 );

}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for help it's working, but i still have 1 problem need your advice. the error and success message disappear after 3 second it's worked, for success how can i include it to reload directly after 3 second?

if i add the reload below the code, it worked but for error message it also will reload the page after show the alert which should show the alert and disappear only, how can i set for error message show alert and disappear only. for success show alert then disappear followed by reload the page. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() { alert("my message"); }, time);
```

In place of JS alert() you can call bootstrap modal alert or Jquery UI dialog like alert.